# Why is printf defined locally as opposed to getchar, which is defined externally?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

When using assembly language with MASM (x86 architecture), one can make use of the standard C functions by including libraries. For example: `printf` and `getchar`.

When compiling with `Asembly With Source Code/FAs` in `Visual Studio` and inspecting the resulting assembly file I stumbled upon the following:

```
PUBLIC  _printf
EXTRN   __imp__getchar : PROC
```

`_printf` is declared `PUBLIC` and defined **locally** (<s>inline</s> within the same file, thus not defined externally in the library file), while `_imp_getchar` is defined **externally**

This is the resulting `_printf` definition the compiler generated while compiling in `debug`:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
__ArgList$ = -20                    ; size = 4
__Result$ = -8                      ; size = 4
__Format$ = 8                       ; size = 4
_printf PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 950  : {

push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 216                ; 000000d8H
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-216]
mov ecx, 54                 ; 00000036H
mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
rep stosd

; 951  :     int _Result;
; 952  :     va_list _ArgList;
; 953  :     __crt_va_start(_ArgList, _Format);

call    ??$__vcrt_va_start_verify_argument_type@QBD@@YAXXZ ; __vcrt_va_start_verify_argument_type<char const * const>
lea eax, DWORD PTR __Format$[ebp+4]
mov DWORD PTR __ArgList$[ebp], eax

; 954  :     _Result = _vfprintf_l(stdout, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);

mov eax, DWORD PTR __ArgList$[ebp]
push    eax
push    0
mov ecx, DWORD PTR __Format$[ebp]
push    ecx
mov esi, esp
push    1
call    DWORD PTR __imp____acrt_iob_func
add esp, 4
cmp esi, esp
call    __RTC_CheckEsp
push    eax
call    __vfprintf_l
add esp, 16                 ; 00000010H
mov DWORD PTR __Result$[ebp], eax

; 955  :     __crt_va_end(_ArgList);

mov DWORD PTR __ArgList$[ebp], 0

; 956  :     return _Result;

mov eax, DWORD PTR __Result$[ebp]

; 957  : }

pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
add esp, 216                ; 000000d8H
cmp ebp, esp
call    __RTC_CheckEsp
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 0
_printf ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
```

## My question

Why is `_printf` defined locally as opposed to `getchar`, which is defined externally?

Comment: Because this is the source for `printf` itself.

Comment: @Jester How does that answer my question in any way? How does that explain `getchar`'s source isn't copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `printf` is right there in your listing. If you remove the assembly, you get:

```
; 950  : {
; 951  :     int _Result;
; 952  :     va_list _ArgList;
; 953  :     __crt_va_start(_ArgList, _Format);
; 954  :     _Result = _vfprintf_l(stdout, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
; 955  :     __crt_va_end(_ArgList);
; 956  :     return _Result;
; 957  : }
```

So, `printf` is an (inline?) function that calls `_vfprintf_l`, which does all the heavy work (and is probably used to implement other C library functions as well).